# extract files from each sub directory separately

Tags: perl, command-line, perl-module

I have two directory with lots of sub directories and files in it
like

```
originalfolder > file1
                 file2
                 folder2 > file3
                           file4
                 folder3 > file1

updatedfolder > file1
                file2
                folder2 > file3
                          file4
                folder3 > file1
```

I have to compare all files in a specific sub directory of originalfolder to same subdirectory in updatedfolder.

It means i have to extact all files from one subdirectory and then move to next subdirectory

But my code extracts all files within a folder.

CODE

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $path = "C:/a";
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                        ->name( '*.*' )
                        ->in( $path); 

my $path1 = "C:/b";
my @files1 = File::Find::Rule->file()
                        ->name( '*.*' )
                        ->in( $path1);
```

I can do the comparing file size part.

I just need help on traversing one sub directory at a time and extracting files into an array.

Window command will also do.. as i can run window command inside Perl if necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the level of subdirectories. Try limiting it to 1 to search only a specific folder:

```
my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                    ->name( '*.*' )
                    ->maxdepth(1)
                    ->in( $path);
```

**Edit**

A code snippet, that would compare two folders and its subfolders without looping through all the sub folders manually.

Try

```
perl compare.pl folder_1 folder_2
```

After saving *compare.pl* with the following content...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find::Rule;

my $first_directory_info    = { directory_name => $ARGV[0] };
my $second_directory_info   = { directory_name => $ARGV[1] };

get_directory_info( $first_directory_info );
get_directory_info( $second_directory_info );

if(
    something_is_wrong( $first_directory_info, $second_directory_info, 1 ) ||
    something_is_wrong( $second_directory_info, $first_directory_info )
)
{
    print "Something is wrong...\n";
}
else
{
    print "Everything is fine...\n";
}

sub get_directory_info
{
    my $directory_info = shift;
    my $directory_name = $directory_info->{ directory_name };

    foreach my $file ( map { $_ =~ /^$directory_name(.*)/; $1 } File::Find::Rule->file->in( $directory_name ) )
    {
        $directory_info->{ files }->{ $file }->{ file_size } = -s $directory_name.$file;
        $directory_info->{ files }->{ $file }->{ writable }  = -w $directory_name.$file;
    }
}

sub something_is_wrong
{
    my $first_directory_info    = shift;
    my $second_directory_info   = shift;
    my $check_attributes        = shift;

    my $result                  = 0; # we assume, everything is fine

    foreach my $key ( keys( $first_directory_info->{ files } ) )
    {
        unless( $second_directory_info->{ files }->{ $key } )
        {
            print "$key is missing in ".$second_directory_info->{ directory_name }."\n";
            $result = 1; # some is wrong
            next;
        }

        if( $check_attributes )
        {
            if(  $first_directory_info->{ files }->{ $key }->{ file_size } !=
                $second_directory_info->{ files }->{ $key }->{ file_size } )
            {
                print "$key has different file size in ".$second_directory_info->{ directory_name }."\n";
                $result = 1;
            }

            if(  $first_directory_info->{ files }->{ $key }->{ writable } !=
                $second_directory_info->{ files }->{ $key }->{ writable } )
            {
                print "$key has different permissions in ".$second_directory_info->{ directory_name }."\n";
                $result = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

exit;
```

Comment: the problem is there are many folders and it should move from one sub folder to another automatically after comparing files

Comment: Then why don't you just take the whole list and simply compare those two arrays if you have to compare the whole amount of subfolders anyway?

Comment: its not so simple. there are more than 20 sub folders each having around 30 files in it

Comment: But the amount of files and folder is not relevant for this question. You could just collect your files in all folders and compare them in one run (and perhaps check in two ways, since one file can be included in the second folder, but not in the first and the other way arround). By using a hash reference or a special object to store some addition info, you could do all this in one run, I will add a code snippet to demonstrate...

Comment: works perfect. just what I needed. i will build my code with this snippet

Answer (score 1):

This will return you the directories under "C:/a". The condition if -d $File::Find::name checks whether its a directory or file before pushing it into the @files array.

```
use File::Find qw(finddepth);

my $path = "C:/a";
my @files;
finddepth(sub {
  return if($_ eq '.' || $_ eq '..');
  push @files, $File::Find::name if -d $File::Find::name;
}, $path);
```

Comment: i am getting error with this code. Undefined subroutine &main::finddepth

Comment: use File::Find qw(finddepth); should be included, my bad!!

Comment: thanks. this doesn't completely answer my question(need to extract files also) but as i am getting all my directories from bottom to top. I can extract files now

Comment: You have the code to extract files, you already posted. Use that one to get files for each directories.

Comment: In case you may be interested, you'll find the following functionally equivalent: `my @subdirs = File::Find::Rule->directory->name(qr/\w/)->maxdepth(1)->in($path);`